# TL-WN8200ND wireless adapter is sopported on linux?

Tags: networking, drivers, 15.04, ndiswrapper

I try alot of methods, buts any work. The wireless adapter work fine in windows, right now i have a VM with WindowsXP 32bits working with the adapter and i have a second boot option with windows 10 without any problem. All work fine.

My firts option was the wrapper for windows drivers. But NDISwrapper and drivers for Windows XP 64 bits freeces my sistem when plug TP Link adapter. I read alot of success case and tutorials but aparently the only way is with XP 32bits drivers, nobody uses 64bits distribution aparenly.

The other way was with native drivers, but aparenly not work correctly for TL Link adapter.

Right now i am trying to shared the wireless connection of the windows VM with the ubuntu host. But its not the best option and notebooks and ssds dont sopport this method...

there is any other option? if exist a posibility to running 32bits drivers  with ndiswrapper on my 64bits Ubuntu maybe this became a solution.

Sorry for my English and thanks for help.

Ubuntu 15.04 64bits - Lenovo ThinkPad t430.

--------------edited------

Here, this is the device: Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:0100

The complete output :

```
    $ lsusb 
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 1bcf:0002 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 5986:02d5 Acer, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21e6 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702 Bluetooth 4.0 [ThinkPad]
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 147e:2020 Upek TouchChip Fingerprint Coprocessor (WBF advanced mode)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:0100  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And this information retrieved from VirtualBox:

```
Name: Realtek 802.11n WLAN Adapter [0200]
ID Vendor: 2357
Id Product : 0100
Rev: 0200
```

Is a Realtek rtl8912cu chipset moded for Tl Link, i supposed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Edited with same info.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms
```

This will install `rtl8192cu` from my PPA in DKMS format.

Comment: Okey, i can now connect to router but the conecction its innestable. Latency are about 900-1500ms with de router vs 2-4ms of my integrated wifi card and lost conexion when tray to use wireless network. In others words, its not working.

Comment: This is a part of the log by dmesg (Router and adapter TP - LInk): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10611346/askubuntu/log

.In AP generated by my android phone connection are stable and probable its because are only one antena. Not multiple antenas like my TP Link router. But its a teory.

Comment: This is a very terse answer - some explanation would definitely not hurt :-)