# USB TP-Link not working properly

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 19.04

I have a TP-Link Wi-Fi USB Adapter, model TL-8200ND Ver. 1.1 and I'm using Ubuntu Disco Dingo 19.04. The system recognizes my adapter, I can see Wi-Fi networks but I can't connect to them. I read about this before and it seems to be like I have some outdated drivers that Ubuntu chooses automatically when updating.

I've seen some apparent solutions to my problem but I'm also a newbie using GNU/Linux-based systems so I have no idea how to completely remove the actual drivers for then installing the correct ones, and also, I don't quite get why I can't install right now the ones supposed to work.

I found this question here so I thought to try something: [Install driver for tl-wn8200nd wireless adapter in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849958/) but nothing seems to work.

Here is what lsusb command shows:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b34d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP2102/CP2109 UART Bridge Controller [CP210x family]
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0a04 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b35b Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03eb:8204 Atmel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 2357:0100 TP-Link TL-WN8200ND [Realtek RTL8192CU]
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and here is what lsmod | grep rtl shows:

```
btrtl                  20480  1 btusb
bluetooth             557056  14 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
```

The device suddenly stops working and powers on constantly in a cycle.

Comment: This will probably help a great deal: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003112/unable-to-install-driver-wn8200nd-v2-rtl8192eu

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The link is for a V2 and I believe that Cerebrain has a V1. They us different chipsets and different drivers.

Comment: Hi, @chili555. I added the information you suggested and thank you for welcoming me. Yes, I have a v1 so the V2 solutions didn't work at all (although I tried them too). I really want this to work because I don't want to come over to Windows again.

Answer (score 1):

Your 2357:0100 device is claimed by two conflicting drivers in Ubuntu 19.04, as well several other earlier versions. The device is often helped to work better by unloading and blacklisting one driver, usually rtl8192cu, and letting the other driver, namely rtl8xxxu, do the work unimpeded.

From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r rtl8192cu
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Is your wireless working as expected now?

**EDIT**: Please be certain that your router is set to a fixed channel, not auto channel select. There are quite a few neighboring SSIDs on channel 11. Consider setting yours to channel 6. Also be sure you are using WPA2-AES and certainly not TKIP.

Then set your regulatory domain explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and close (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

Reboot the computer and the router and let us hear your report.

Comment: No, it's not working yet. It still turns off randomly and when trying to connect to a network it never does (I know for a fact that it should connect, it did before when using Windows 7).

Comment: Please run: `dmesg | grep -e rtl -e wlx` and also: `nmcli dev wifi list` and paste the results here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I've run the commands and here is the pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kXKh9rBmFK/

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: In the end I couldn't fix it, I didn't understand that code part. I went back to Ubuntu 18.04 but the problem remains. I think I'll create a new question and put all the relevant information from the beginning. Thank you!

Comment: No matter which version, my recommendations will be the same. If there is something above that you don't understand, I'll be very happy to help.