# Ubuntu PC vs ethernet

Tags: networking, router, amd-processor, nic, amd-ryzen

I have been experiencing a conflict so bizarre between my ubuntu PC vs my tp-link router that I don't know where or what to be searching for. A few months ago, I assembled an AMD-ryzen + ASUS prime computer - and installed ubuntu 19.10 on it.

This machine has been great, no problems whatsoever - except that it keeps tripping my TPLink router (connected over ethernet), **literally**, in the sense that the physical port it is connected to stops working. No other device can connect to it after it has tripped. The only way around it is to connect the computer to a new port and finally to restart the router.

To clarify this:

a) **It is the router that trips rather than a failure on the computer side**.  If I connect other machines to a previously-tripped port - they won't connect either.  And if I connect this Ubuntu machine to a **not**-previously-tripped physical port - it works - until this port eventually gets tripped. The duration for this is quite random - from a few hours to a few days I do this until all the ports on the router have tripped after which I have to restart the router. And the musical chairs start afresh.

b) **It is definitely this computer that causes the router port to trip**. I have another 2 machines connected to this router. They have been running quite happily on it for years with no complaints. However, they will refuse to work on any physical port that the Ubuntu machine has tripped.

Any suggestions as to where I should start ? This problem is so strange that I don't even know what to google for. Also, apologies if this is not the right channel for this question and would appreciate pointers to the right one.

Comment: I'm not sure what "***trip***" means but does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142802/usb-tp-link-not-working-properly

Comment: It literally trips the port - in the sense that the port stops working. No other device can connect to it. (will add to the question ) . Also thanks for the  link - unfortunately my problem is over ethernet not wifi.

Comment: Have you made sure that no other devices are tripping that port?  If it is only that system that is doing it you might have a falling NIC / MB sending too much power on a low power connection.  Maybe a short in the cable?  There is voltage that runs on the ports, see:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_twisted_pair

Comment: Yes - I have 2 other machines connected to that router (over ethernet also) - and never had any problems with them. Further more - these machines won't connect to a port that the Ubuntu+AMD machine has tripped (until I restart the router)

Comment: You might also want to see:  https://community.tp-link.com/en/business/forum/topic/85051?page=2